# iRobot Create 2 - How did I get weird data from the serial port?

Tags: irobot-create

I'm new to Roomba Create2.

I just want the program to send and receive data of the bumper sensor only.

I tried this code on an Arduino Uno:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "roombaDefines.h"
int rxPin = 10;
int txPin = 11;
int sensorbytes;
SoftwareSerial Roomba(rxPin, txPin);
void setup()
{
  Roomba.begin(19200);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ddPin, OUTPUT);
  wakeUp ();   // Wake-up Roomba
  startSafe(); // Start Roomba in Safe Mode
  setPowerLED(128, 255);
  delay(1000);
  setPowerLED(128, 0);
  delay(1000);
}
void loop() 
{  
  Roomba.write(142);
  Roomba.write(7);
  delay(100);
  sensorbytes = Roomba.read();

   if (sensorbytes!=0 )
   {
    setPowerLED(255,255);
    Serial.println(sensorbytes);
   }
   else
   {
    setPowerLED(255,0);
    Serial.println("not_Press");
   }
   delay(100);
}
```

The robot code works fine for a period of time but after about two minutes I got some weird data from the robot (it shows in my serial monitor) and it makes my program seem to delay and crash.

So I tried to check where it comes from

```
void loop() 
{

int i = 0;

  while(Roomba.available() ) {
    byte c = Roomba.read();
    sensorbytes = c;
    Serial.println(sensorbytes);
    i++;
  }
  delay(150);
}
```

to check that the robot sends data via the serial port or not. Even if I don't command it, I get a packet of data, maybe every two minutes:

```
32
32
32
32
70
108
97
115
104
32
67
82
67
32
115
117
99
148
205
205
233
32
48
120
48
32
40
48
120
48
41
10
13
```

and it is the same.  So I think that the Roomba Create2 will send data via the serial port every two minutes.

Can I avoid that data?

Comment: `can i avoid that data ??` ... it is unclear what you are asking ..... are you asking how to stop roomba from sending it?

Comment: decimal `32` is ascii `space` and decimal `10` and `13` is ascii `newline` and `carriage return` ............. put the values into a single string `32 32 32 32 70 108 97 115 104 32 67 82 67 32 115 117 99 148 205 205 233 32 48 120 48 32 40 48 120 48 41 10 13`   ............... then convert to ASCII at a site like this on https://www.branah.com/ascii-converter ............. the result is this `.    Flash CRC suc ÍÍé 0x0 (0x0)` ...... it looks like a part of a response to a command

Comment: Thank you for your reply
for my understanding if i did not  send command to roomba it should not send me back the data right ? 

but i get this data even i i didnt command it

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the iRobot Create 2 OI spec
https://www.irobotweb.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/iRobot_Roomba_600_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf

I'm using a different controller so I can't test your code. Just be sure you are set for 115,200 baud.

You might also want to try sending a 128,7 command to fully reset the Create 2 before starting to send your 142,7 sensor read command which should only return a single byte on every command

You might also want to send the recommended "start" command

[image]